# Google Map API3 Map.fitBounds is not working on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am using webservice to load markers from sql server. and a cluster-er to group those markers, then I re-size the map to fit the bounds using  map.fitBounds(bounds).. it works fine on chrome and firefox,, BUT not working on IE,, it gives me an error of Out of stack space in one of google map api 3 files (main.js)

you can check this demo for the issue :  http://aprilit.com/gmap/default.aspx
here is a part of my code.

> function LoadMap(arrMarkers) {
>
> ```
> var mapOptions = {
>     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
>     streetViewControl: false
> }
>
>
> var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
> var markers = [];
> var tempCount = 0;
> var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
> for (var XMLCount = 0; XMLCount < arrMarkers.length; XMLCount++) {
>     var Points = $.parseXML(arrMarkers[XMLCount]);
>     $Markers = $(Points).find("Marker");
>     for (var i = 0; i < $Markers.length; i++) {
>         var tempID = $Markers.find('mid')[i].innerHTML;
>         var tempCID = $Markers.find('cid')[i].innerHTML;
>         var myLatLng =
> ```
>
> new google.maps.LatLng($Markers.find('lt')[i].innerHTML,
>
> $Markers.find('lg')[i].innerHTML);
>
> markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
>
> ```
>             position: myLatLng,
>
>             map: map,
>
>             animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
>
>
>             markerid: $Markers.find('mid')[i].innerHTML,
>
>             catid: $Markers.find('cid')[i].innerHTML,
>             icon: LoadIcon($Markers.find('cimg')[i].innerHTML)
>         }));
>
>         infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
>             content: "loading..."
>         });
>
>         google.maps.event.addListener(markers[tempCount], 'click', function () {
>             infowindow.setContent('<div ><img src="img/assets/loader.gif"/>
>       Loading../div>');
>
>             infowindow.open(map, this);
>             $.ajax(
>              {
>                  type: "POST",
>                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
>                  url: "Markers.asmx/GetMarker",
>                  data: JSON.stringify({ MarkerID: this['markerid'],
>                        CategoryID: this['catid'] }), 
>                  dataType: "json",
>                  success: function (msg) {
>                      infowindow.setContent(formatInfoDivHTML(msg.d));
>                  }
>              });
>             map.panTo(this.getPosition());
>             infowindow.open(map, this);
>         });
>
>         bounds.extend(myLatLng);
>         tempCount++;
>     }
> }    
> //////////////////////////Here is the problem
> map.fitBounds(bounds);
> var mcOptions = { gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 12 };
> var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
> google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
>
> }
> ```

thanks and ill appreciate your help

also note that I am using fitbounds in other places and it is working just fine.

Just for the reference,, when I checked with an older version of google chrome (Version 31.0.1650.57 m) it gave me the same error..but when  I updated chrome the issue has gone

Comment: I suspect the issue is your data. Do all the markers have coordinates? Are all the coordinates valid? Are all the coordinates numbers?

Comment: @geocodezip Yes all the data is fine,, and it works normally on other browsers.. go check this link for a demo  http://aprilit.com/gmap/default.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue,,

It appears that IE doesn't support the innerHTML property I used here:

> $Markers.find('mid')[i].innerHTML

or any where else where I am retrieving the data from my xml fields.

so it had to be replaced with the the  textContent property as this:

> $Markers.find('mid')[i].textContent;

and that solves the whole issue.!!

thanks for your help guys

Comment: That's a well known bug of IE, although it is recommended to stay away from innerHTML anyway.

Comment: @geocodezip thanks,, I'll accept the answer tomorrow when I am allowed

Answer (score 0):

Your SplitXML function is appending an extra null element to the array of markers.  Most versions of IE don't like that.